# How to configure android packagename within Maui android project?

Tags: c#, maui

I have created a dummy maui app.  I managed to get the package name with the following code after following [App information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/app-information?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android)

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<ul>
    <li>Name: @name</li>
    <li>Package: @package</li>
    <li>Version: @version</li>
    <li>Build: @build</li>
</ul>

@code {

    private string name = AppInfo.Current.Name;
    private string package = AppInfo.Current.PackageName;
    private string version = AppInfo.Current.VersionString;
    private string build = AppInfo.Current.BuildString;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
       
    }
}
```

As you can see from the following image this does work it displays my android application information.  but ...

[image]

My question is how to configure this Package name shows as com.companyname.blazortest.  I would like to be able to supply my company name

There is no appsettings.json file, its not in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Im a bit stumped as to where this is configured.

Comment: In the project properties, under the Android section (at the very bottom) there is an option for `Application package name` does changing this do the trick?

Comment: Have you tried to change app identifier in your .csproj?
<!-- App Identifier -->
  <ApplicationId>com.companyname.app.maui</ApplicationId>

Comment: You could also try adding an attribute called `package` to the `manifest` element. I believe this what project property does. `<manifest xmlns:android="..." package="com.company.app`

Comment: @RyanThomas in properties. I dont have application package name.

Comment: @RyanThomas adding package to the manifest worked.

Comment: @puko yes I can see it in the project file, editing the project file seems to be a bit hard core to me.  It should be a setting you can change in the project.   Can you both post an anwser?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change it manually in your .csproj file

```
<!-- App Identifier --> 
<ApplicationId>com.companyname.app.maui</ApplicationId>
```

or you can change it in project properties

[image]

or if you want to change it in android project only you can do it under Android section (it will change your manifest file)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am in Rider which i think currently has limited Maui support.  Im not seeing it in the project settings here.    It may only work in Visual studio currently

Comment: Probably yes. I never tried it in Rider. You can do it manually by editing android manifest or .csproj so far ...

Comment: I have bug reported it over on Rider already.  Thanks for the tip.   This will defiantly help someone with Visual studio in the future.